# Change Value in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, insert, ms-access-2007

I have a table full of code IDs and their descriptions in access. And in another table is a field that has code IDs that correlate to the IDs in the Codes table.  I am trying to design a macro that when executed will replace the code ID in the second table with the correct description but I am unsure a way to do this. I was thinking of using a SQL `Insert` query to do so but am unsure of what the statement would look like.

`JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.FORMULARYID, ReasonCodes.Description
FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable,ReasonCodes
INNER JOIN ReasonCodes
ON ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.ReasonCode=ReasonCodes.CodeID
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? the current setup is correct. You have a RELATIONSHIP defined between the two tables. The ID is what is stored, when you need to see the Text description you simply JOIN the two tables and get the right data. Leave it as it is.

Comment: I would do that but I need to export the table to an excel spreadsheet and the description needs to be there.

Comment: Yes still, you can create a Query with the correct JOIN and export the Query. Still no reason to edit. Editing will cause instability to data, changes to Forms and code - a very painful task for something that has a better solution.

Comment: I wrote this JOIN statement but for some reason it won't run due to a syntax error. I am very confused why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HansUp I am unsure of the syntax error in the Join statement above.

Comment: Doesn't it point you to the line of the syntax error?

Comment: Yes it points to `ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.FORMULARYID` but I don't see the error.

Comment: That table and field exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention *ReasonCodes* only once in your query's `FROM` clause.

Change this ...

```sql
FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable,ReasonCodes
INNER JOIN ReasonCodes
```

To this ...

```sql
FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable
INNER JOIN ReasonCodes
```

As general advice, I suggest you begin your queries in the Access query designer.  At least choose the data sources (tables or saved queries) and set up joins there.

With your original example, the designer would have applied an alias, *ReasonCodes_1*, for one of those duplicate *ReasonCodes* names.  And that could be an early warning that the data sources aren't correct.